# Access stock data and visualize it on a wix website

Tags: javascript, json, velo, alpha-vantage

I try to access stock prices and plot them on a wix website using java script.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    const apiUrl = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query? 
       function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=NVAX&interval=1min&apikey=API_KEY';

    function getStockPrice() {
        fetch(apiUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            const stockData = data['Time Series (1min)']; 
            const lastRefreshedTime = data['Meta Data']['3. Last Refreshed'].replace('T', ' '); 
            const latestPrice = stockData[lastRefreshedTime]['4. close']; 
            
            $w("chart").text = `current price: ${latestPrice}`;
        })
        // .catch(error => {
        //     console.error('Failure to retrieve stock price data:', error);
        // });
    }

    function updateStockPrice() {
        getStockPrice(); 
        setTimeout(updateStockPrice, 60000); 
    }

    updateStockPrice();
});
```

The request seems to work as in the console appears data:

{...}jsonTableCopy JSON

Meta Data: {...}jsonTableCopy JSON

1. Information: "Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume"
2. Symbol: "NVAX"
3. Last Refreshed: "2023-08-31 19:59:00"
4. Interval: "1min"
5. Output Size: "Compact"
6. Time Zone: "US/Eastern"

Time Series (1min): {...}

But every 60 seconds there appears an error message:

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2023-08-31 19:59:00')

I don't understand the problem. Any Ideas?

Comment: if you `console.log(stockData)` does it contain a key matching `lastRefreshedTime`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by that. I am new to this stuff. I have only worked with Python until now.

Comment: the error seems to be on this line: `const latestPrice = stockData[lastRefreshedTime]['4. close'];` it basically cannot access `data['Time Series (1min)']['2023-08-31 19:59:00']` because that's undefined. So, if you `console.log(stockData)`, can you actually see the "datetime" key specified in last refresh?

Comment: I changed it to daily instead of intraday data but didnt change anything I think. There is a long list of week days looking like this:

Time Series (Daily): {...}jsonTableCopy JSON
2023-08-31: {...}jsonTableCopy JSON
1. open: "8.3600"
2. high: "8.5700"
3. low: "8.0000"
4. close: "8.0000"
5. volume: "7639386"
2023-08-30: {...}
2023-08-29: {...}
2023-08-28: {...}
2023-08-25: {...}
...
and so on. You can open each day.


Is this what you mean?